# C# I want one inherited class to SET only and other inherited class to GET only

Tags: c#, inheritance, get, set

I have a .cs file called ModelDonation.cs and it contains 3 classes. One is my base class that I want my other classes to inherit from. Then I have two classes that inherit from the base class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace GiftAidCalculator.TestConsole
{

     abstract class Donation
    {
        private decimal DonationAmountTotal;
        public virtual decimal donationAmountTotal
        {
            get
            {
                return donationAmountTotal = DonationAmountTotal;
            }
            set
            {
                DonationAmountTotal = donationAmountTotal;
            }
        }
        private decimal VAT;
        public virtual decimal vAT
        {
            get
            {
                return vAT = VAT;
            }
        }      
    }

     class Donor : Donation
     {
         public override decimal vAT
         {
             get
             {
                 return vAT = VAT;
             }
         }
     }

     class SiteAdministrator : Donation
     {
         public decimal vAT
         {
             get
             {
                 return vAT = VAT;
             }
             set
             {
                 VAT = vAT;
             }
         }
     } 
}
```

I don't want my donor class to be able to set the VAT. A donor can GET the VAT to see what a donation is made up of.

I want the SiteAdministrator to be able to SET and GET the VAT. He is the one that would change the VAT rate.

Where my problem lies is using inheritance in C#. I am not sure how to implement it the way I want it.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure you are going around the modelling in the correct manner. `Donor` and `SiteAdministrator` sound like user roles to be, and would never inherit from a `Donation`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in using inheritance to solve a problem best solved through using interfaces and composition.

Define two interfaces:

```
public interface IVatControllable
{
    decimal Vat { get; set; }
}

public interface IVatGettable
{
    decimal Vat { get; }
}
```

and have your classes implement the correct interface:

```
public class Donor : IVatGettable
{
    public decimal Vat { get { ... } }
}
```

etc.

There should be no need to complicate your design through inheritance in this case.

Comment: Thanks that works. I need to work on taking advantage of OOP more and using interfaces has the effect I want.

Comment: @nickgowdy Glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 1):

Make propertyb get only, and add simply one method to a new interface.

Example:

```
/* This isnterface holds method that suitable 
 * for administration related tasks
**/
public interface IAdministrator {
   void SetVAT(..);
  ...
  //other Administration related methods
}

/* Generic, abstract class for Donation description and management*/
abstract class Donation {
   public virtual decimal vAT
   {
        get
        {
            return vAT = VAT;
        }
    }      
}

/*Administrator is able act as Donation AND as Administrator*/
public class Administrator : IAdministrator, Donation
{
}
```

So manifest logical separation of reposnsibility in your code too. `Administrator` is `Donator`, but `Administrator` too.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to keep the VAT get/set properties together, you could define two interfaces:

```
public interface IVATFullAccess {
    public decimal VAT { get; set; }
};
public interface IVATReader {
    public decimal VAT { get; }
};

public class Administrator: IVATFullAccess,... { ... } // has full access to VAT
public class Donation : IVATReader,...  { ... } // has read-only access to VAT
```

You can scale this technique to include additional access controls -- C# allows a class to inherit from multiple interfaces (similar to C++ multiple inheritance).

```
public class Administrator: IVATFullAccess, IAccountCreate, IEmailNotify, ... {}
public class Donation : IVATReader, IAccountIndex {}
```

If you're coming from a language like C++, think of an interface as a virtual base class.